# Asking for an element from a Python set

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

Is there a simple way to ask a set for an element in Python? Here are some methods I have used:

```
elem = myset.pop(); myset.add(elem)
elem = random.choice(list(myset))
elem = list(myset)[0]
```

Each of these methods are inefficient and clumsy.

Is there a way to just ask something like `elem = myset.get()` which returns an element of the set without removing it? Just like a non-removing pop()?

(Of course the method would likely return the same element each time, until the set was changed by other code, but this is still useful.)

Comment: The answers provided so far all use iterators, but I wouldn't say that's a readability issue lie you mentioned in user2357112s answer. Iterators are something even inexperienced programmers should get into. One should not omit useful language features just because somebody coming from C doesn't know them

Comment: @Lord I agree in principle. Most programmers will see these lines and think "that is a bit odd". The first creates an iterator, fetches one value, and then destroys it. The second starts looping through the set and immediately exits without executing any statements. Both are efficient, but unless commented, many a programmer will ponder (at least briefly) how to do this better.

Answer (score 2):

```
elem = next(iter(myset))
```

or

```
for elem in myset:
    break
```

If you find that these code snippets confuse people, you can wrap them in a function with a nice name:

```
def arbitrary_element_of(thing):
    for elem in thing:
        return elem
    raise ValueError("Argument is empty")
```

Comment: Both are a step forward in efficiency +1. There is a readability issue though. I would need to comment that line of code each time I used one of these. Python programmers without much experience would wonder what it does.

Comment: @CarpetPython: Consider wrapping them in a function, then.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> myset = (1,2,3,4,10)
>>> gen = (iter(myset))
>>> next(gen)
1
>>> next(gen)
2
>>> next(gen)
3
>>> next(gen)
4
>>> next(gen)
10
>>> next(gen)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like this which destructively and arbitrarily iterates over the contents of a temporary dictionary created from the elements of the set.

```
def get_elem(s):
    d = dict.fromkeys(s)
    while d:
        yield d.popitem()[0]
```